# How would I query dbpedia for a list of programming languages?

Tags: syntax, sparql, dbpedia

I go to the [dbPedia SPARQL Endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and type:

```
select distinct ?Programming_language where {[] a ?Programming_language} LIMIT 100
```

But it just spits out a generic list of concepts like Animal, Book, Place.

What would be the correct syntax for listing 100 programming languages?

Answer (score 1):

Aha, based on the [soccer example](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20?player%20%7B%0D%0A?s%20foaf%3apage%20?player.%0D%0A?s%20rdf%3atype%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerPlayer%3E%20.%0D%0A?s%20dbpedia2%3aposition%20?position%20.%0D%0A?s%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/clubs%3E%20?club%20.%0D%0A?club%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/capacity%3E%20?cap%20.%0D%0A?s%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace%3E%20?place%20.%0D%0A?place%20?population%20?pop.%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B?s%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/number%3E%20?tricot.%7D%0D%0AFilter%20%28?population%20in%20%28%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/populationEstimate%3E,%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/populationCensus%3E,%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/statPop%3E%20%29%29%0D%0AFilter%20%28xsd%3aint%28?pop%29%20%3E10000000%20%29%20.%0D%0AFilter%20%28xsd%3aint%28?cap%29%20%3C40000%20%29%20.%0D%0AFilter%20%28?position%20=%20%22Goalkeeper%22@en%20%7C%7C%20?position%20=%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Goalkeeper_%2528association_football%2529%3E%20%7C%7C%20?position%20=%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Goalkeeper_%2528football%2529%3E%29%0D%0A%7D%20Limit%201000).

```
SELECT DISTINCT  ?lang {
?lang rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ProgrammingLanguage>
} Limit 1000
```